# test if property in entity can be ordered using orderBy

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

i am using a linq dynamic to do a dynamic orderBy. How do I get only the property names of an entity that is must have a type that is order comparable. The entity has base types (string, ints) and complex objects which I don't the user to filter by.

```
var OrderByOptions = typeof (Project).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList(); //I only want order comparable property names here

var userSelectable = 2;

var pjs = _pjRepo.Projects.Where(x => x.Active == true).OrderBy(OrderByOptions[userSelectable]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This if you want to handle both `IComparable` and `IComparable<>`

```
var OrderByOptions = (from p in typeof(Project).GetProperties()
                      let type = p.PropertyType
                      where typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(type) || 
                            typeof(IComparable<>).MakeGenericType(type).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                      select p.Name).ToArray();
```

Note that if you are doing server-side ordering, there is no guarantee that `IComparable`/`IComparable<T>` will be the same in SQL. For example:

```
bool b1 = typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int?));
bool b2 = typeof(IComparable<int?>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int?));
```

both return false. But a nullable int is surely comparable in SQL.

Perhaps a white-list would be better.

```
public static readonly HashSet<Type> ComparableTypes = new HashSet<Type>
{
    typeof(bool), typeof(bool?),
    typeof(char), typeof(char?),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(sbyte), typeof(sbyte?), typeof(byte), typeof(byte?),
    typeof(short), typeof(short?), typeof(ushort), typeof(ushort?),
    typeof(int), typeof(int?), typeof(uint), typeof(uint?),
    typeof(long), typeof(long?), typeof(ulong), typeof(ulong?),
    typeof(float), typeof(float?),
    typeof(double), typeof(double?),
    typeof(decimal), typeof(decimal?),
    typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTime?),
    typeof(DateTimeOffset), typeof(DateTimeOffset?),                
    typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(TimeSpan?),
    typeof(Guid), typeof(Guid?),
};

var OrderByOptions = (from p in typeof(Project).GetProperties()
                      let type = p.PropertyType
                      where ComparableTypes.Contains(type)
                      select p.Name).ToArray();
```

Comment: You should swap the position of `type` and `typeof(IComparable)`, I did the same way but I realized that `typeof(IComparable)` would go first. The `IsAssignableFrom` method sometimes confuses me. A small test `typeof(int).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IComparable)) = false`? but `typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(int)) = true` <== That's what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

I think all the class supporting `order comparability` should implement `IComparable` and its generic version:

```
var OrderByOptions = typeof (Project).GetProperties()
                                     .Where(p=>typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
                                     .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Not `p.GetType()`, `p.PropertyType`